# An algorithm for the simultaneous Diophantine approximation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

The celebrated theorem by Dirichlet states that for given real numbers $\{\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_N \}$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $q\leq 1/\epsilon^N $ such that

$$\max \{ \parallel q \gamma_1 \parallel, \parallel q \gamma_2 \parallel, \ldots, \parallel q \gamma_N \parallel \}  \leq 1 /\epsilon . $$

The problem is, is there any algorithm for finding such a $q$?

ps. The $N=1$ case is trivial. Let us do $N>  1$.

Comment: In case $N=1$, the $q$'s are given by the denominators of the rational convergents to $\gamma$.  These are generated recursively along with the continued fraction entries for $\gamma$.

Comment: Yes. I now emphasize $N>1$.

Comment: There are continued fraction algorithms, I believe. And, of course, you can loop over the $N^{1/\epsilon}$ possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

One good reference for this kind of problem is:

Berthé, Valerie. "Multidimensional Euclidean algorithms, numeration and substitutions." Integers B 11 (2011): A2.

In particular, you may find chapters 4, 5 and 6 useful. There are alternatives to the Markovian continued fraction algorithms and the lattice reduction algorithms described in the above survey. Here is one such algorithm in dimension two that works reasonably well:

[image]